# How can I customize the "Authorization required" dialogue box in .htacess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a webpage with password restriction via `.htaccess` and when I access the page I get a box asking for username and password. Nothing strange there.

I've customized the error message for 401 so that users get some useful info if they enter wrong password.

However, I'd like to customize the text in the dialogue box in the box requesting username and password. The dialogue that looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to change the text *"is requesting your username and password. The site says: “Password Protected Area"* to some information about where to get the login information. Is this possible by editing the `.htaccess`? I cannot find anything about this. I only found how to customize the actual error pages.

I don't have access to the actual web server, since it is a web hotel, so I cannot do anything there.

PS

Although I doubt it would work, I could accept a PHP solution.

EDIT:

Found solution right after I posted this. See below.

Answer (score -1):

And of course I find the solution after googling just one more time after posting the question.

The solution is variable AuthName. Add this line to `.htaccess`:

```
AuthName <message>
```

and the dialogue box will say:

> is requesting your username and password. The site says: "<​message>"

Comment: This doesnt work with most browsers. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/60788043/980414