# AuthName in .htaccess not displayed in Chrome

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I am trying to secure a website with an `.htaccess` file with Apache2. It works well but the message specified with the `AuthName` line is not visible on Chrome (but it is visible on Firefox !). What should I do to make it visible on Chrome?

Here is my `.htaccess` file

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthFile "/etc/apache2/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

On Firefox the pop-up tells

> The site ... is requesting your username and password. The site says: "Restricted Access"

But on Chrome it only tells

> Sign in

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What should I do to make it visible on Chrome?

There is nothing you *can* do.

The browser decides whether it wants to display this information to the user in some way, or not.

---

The phrasing used in the Apache documentation already hints at that (highlights by me) -

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_core.html#authname:

> The string provided for the AuthName is what will appear in the password dialog provided by **most** browsers.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html#gettingitworking:

> The AuthName directive sets the Realm to be used in the authentication. The realm serves two major functions. First, the client **often** presents this information to the user as part of the password dialog box. Second, it is used by the client to determine what password to send for a given authenticated area.

Comment: it seems that FireFox has started to hide this information as well...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround which can give some info for your unlucky visitor, using custom error document feature after the login attempt fails:

Put this line into your .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 401 YYYY-MM-DDTHHMM-Site-update-under-way-Estimate-30-min
```

The continuous text seems to get displayed after login fails or is canceled. No dots (.) or colons (:) allowed. Of course it should represent a valid filename, but if the user has no access to public_html due to login fail a file maybe can't be served anyway. If You can serve a proper 401 error page, You can explain the situation there.

(edit 1) Maybe this behaviour is a curiosity in my case with shared hosting. The shared server there seems to be nginx which I guess "is forced" to accept .htaccess directives.

(edit 2) Confirmed this behaviour also with Apache 2.4 server